# Remove product by id api/order/{id} EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to make a remove method from db by id.
My problem is in productcontroller.cs, Got wrong argument when I type `id` in `var product = await _productRepository.RemoveProductByIdAsync()`

ProductController.cs

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveProduct(long id)
        {
            var product = await _productRepository.RemoveProductByIdAsync();
            if ( product is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            
            product.Remove(RemoveProduct);
            return NoContent();


        }
```

ProductRespository.cs

```
 public async Task RemoveProductByIdAsync(Product product)
        {
            _context.Products.Remove(product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

IProductRespository.cs

```
Task RemoveProductByIdAsync(Product product);
```

Comment: There are a lot of things "off" in the example you've given. 1) it's not httpput, but httpdelete in this case. 2) you get the id, but you never pass it on into the method 3) you expect a Product, but you never supply one.. 4) Idempotency? If you want to delete a product and it's not found - is that not exactly the intended action? Why return 404?

Comment: I forgot about httpdelete, my fault. about 4) a not found product, can't be deleted, thats why I want to return 404.

Comment: That's why I hinted on Idempotency :) - look it up

Comment: Okey, I know what you mean, but still I can't find the problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
await _productRepository.RemoveProductByIdAsync();
```

does require a product
You get the id from the task

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveProduct(long id)
```

So first get your product, for instance like this:

```
var prod = await _productRepository.GetProductByIdAsync(id);
```

and then delete it; like so:

```
await _productRepository.RemoveProductByIdAsync(prod);
```

in total:

```
var prod = await _productRepository.GetProductByIdAsync(id);
if (prod != null)
{
     await _productRepository.RemoveProductByIdAsync(prod);
}
```

and don't throw a 404 - because you already intended to delete it anyway

Comment: if this does answer your question mark as solution btw

Comment: Something still is wrong, like in ProductRespository.cs got `not all code paths return a value`

Comment: return Ok() or something after that?... this is your code, not mine